# django URL regex optional match (tastypie)

Tags: regex, django, tastypie

I'm using [tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/) for providing an API for my application. I prefer to have URLs without trailing slashes. I prefer `/api/v1/entry/set/1;3` rather than `/api/v1/entry/set/1;3/`. I've turned off django's [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) and turned on [TASTYPIE_ALLOW_MISSING_SLASH](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#tastypie-allow-missing-slash).

This works nicely, except for get_multiple (/set) which tastypie notes in its documentation can't work without a trailing slash. The URL regex from the tastypie code is:

```
# Due to the way Django parses URLs, ``get_multiple`` won't work without
# a trailing slash.
...
url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/set/(?P<%s_list>\w[\w/;-]*)/$" %
             (self._meta.resource_name, self._meta.detail_uri_name),
             self.wrap_view('get_multiple'), name="api_get_multiple"),
...
```

I've verified that this is true. `/api/v1/notes/set/2;1` and `/api/v1/notes/set/2;1/` match fine if APPEND_SLASH is enabled, but changing the `/` in the above regex to `/?` makes it so django does not match the pattern.

The pattern matches correctly when I try using the `re` module manually. Why doesn't django match the URL without the trailing slash?

Comment: What you're doing seems correct.  I can only think that perhaps you're not updating the right code...  Try replacing the regex with something ridiculous to see.

Comment: I made sure I'm editing the right code. The comment indicates that this behavior is what's supposed to happen. The question I really have is why

Comment: That is just the way that tasty pie likes to do things.  It is truly annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. My [pull request](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/527) was merged June 14th, 2012.